# How to configure Maven to download through proxy?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm fallowing the `Spring` [tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#initial) to create my first `RESTApi`.

But in the step when I need run the project using `./mvnw spring-boot:run`, it's returning connection time out error.

I know in the company is using a proxy which I need configure my `APT` and `Docker` manually to be work.

I had configure in the `~/.m2/settings.xml` fallowing settings:

```
<settings>
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <id>http</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>myhost</host>
    <port>my_post</port>
  <proxy>
  <proxy>
    <id>http</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http2</protocol>
    <host>myhost</host>
    <port>my_post</port>
  <proxy>
</proxies>
</settings>
```

Comment: So, what error do you get? Also the closing tag at the end is wrong, it should be `</settings>`.

Comment: What about the username and password? https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html